# Why doesn't model event handler get called upon it's deletion?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

According to the accepted answer  in [Using Model Events Listener in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818317/using-model-events-listener-in-laravel-5), the following code should work normally:

```php
class Question extends Model
{
    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }

    // this is a recommended way to declare event handlers
    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        // before delete() method call this
        static::deleting(function($question) {
            $question->answers()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

However, after performing the following actions in `php artisan tinker`:

```php
$q = App\Question::create()
$q->answers()->create()
$q->delete()
```

The answer still persists in the database. It seems, that the event handler on Question model does not get triggered. How do I fix this?

Comment: try to use it in the `static::deleted` instead

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes thanks for the reply. Tried that to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would answer with a comment if I could.

Hi, as far as I know the deleting event is only getting fired if you delete each model explicitly.

From answer in [Soft Delete Cascading with Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190586/soft-delete-cascading-with-laravel-5-2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does explicit deletion mean?

Comment: You must go element by element. Example: `static::deleting(function($question) {
      foreach ($question->answers()->get() as $answer) {
        $answer->delete();
      }
    });`

Answer (score 1):

You should add to AppServiceProvider in boot action you code, like this

```
\App\Questions::deleting(function($answers) {
           $answers = Answers::where('question_id', '=', $answer->id)
                   ->get();
           foreach ($answers as $answer) {
               // and here delete questions
           }

       });
```