# Laravel eloquent updateOrCreate(), do something only if create?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I use in my laravel 5.5 app `Model::updateOrCreate()`, it works, but by 1 parameter I wish to do something only if entry is creating and not updating model, is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is using [laravel Model events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29818317) !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [updateOrCreate](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L391) returns a model instance where you can check for recent creation

An example could be the following pseudo code

```
$model = Model::updateOrCreate($data);

if($model->wasRecentlyCreated) {
    // Do logic only when the model was created
}
```